# Tablesorter Custom Filter to show only available

Tags: jquery, filter, tablesorter

I'm working with Tablesorter and have been able to use it to do amazing things, but one thing I can not figure it is in filters.  I'd like to have a method or custom filter to make dropdown boxes but only list availabe rows (cells without the filtered class)

example:

I have 2 rows one with names the other with courses

if in the first row I select a name, the drop down the in the second row should only show the courses available to that user.  Currently all items form teh second row are show even if they are filtered.

so my question is

1) is there a class I'm missing to turn this time of functionality on like 'filter-select only-not-filtered' or 'filter-select-available' or something?

2) if one doesn't exist is this possible with custom filters and if so what would it look like, I have been on the wiki for 2 days now and there is no good example of a custom filter and I can't find a list of classes and what they do in filters.

Thanks and this is my first post here hopefully I got things right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrote the change and submitted it to tablesorter since it has to be done in the widget plugin.

https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/292